# Find customer by postal code in Magento

Tags: magento, filter

How can I find a list of customers that have a specific postal code?

I have tried using the `Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection')` but this only allows me to filter on id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something similar should work - didn't test it though:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('postcode','11-111');
$collection->joinTable(
    array( 'customer'=>'customer/entity' ),
    'entity_id = parent_id',
    array('*')
);
```

Comment: Works fine, the join is not even required. Thank you

Comment: the joined table should allow you to get more info about the particular customer without any further load() calls - that's why it is there - but of course if you do not need any extra data from customer then it is not needed.